# Signaling pathways with Receptor Tyrosine Kinase clarification

Tags: biochemistry, homework, protein-binding

This question is regarding signaling pathways with RTKs, Receptor Tyrosine Kinase.  The picture posted has one thing wrong with it and I am supposed to figure out what that is.

[image]

What I have come up with so far is that the Ras protein shown that goes on to activate RAF, has GDP attached to it.  This cannot be true from what I understand, as Ras must have GTP bound to it in order for Ras to stay in it's closed conformation.  The closed conformation is what activates the rest of the signals.

I am wondering if I am correct in my assumption, or if there is something else in the diagram I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The active form of Ras should definitely be bound to GTP, to activate Raf. I don't see anything else wrong with the diagram. For reference, here is another useful [diagram the pathway](http://www.nature.com/nrclinonc/journal/v11/n7/fig_tab/nrclinonc.2014.83_F1.html) from Nature.

Comment: Please add some more details to your answer.